# Apache 2.4: is it possible to authenticate a subdirectory independently of parent directory authentication?

Tags: apache, authentication, configuration, config

After extensive googling, I've found many examples of:

1. Parent directory is open to public, but subdirectory and/or specific file(s) require(s) authentication
2. Parent directory requires authentication, but subdirectory and/or specific file(s) are open to the public

These two objectives both seem easier and possible to achieve.

However, I can't seem to find a question, or an answer to how to do the following:

3. Parent directory authenticates to a group and user password file, while subdirectory authenticates to an independent group and user password file.

Is this possible?

---

e.g.

given:
`/wwwroot/dir`
`/wwwroot/dir/subdir`

`httpd.conf`:

```
   <Directory "/wwwroot/dir">
      Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Files"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile /passwd/passwd.users
      AuthGroupFile /passwd/groups
      Require group some.People
   </Directory>

   <Directory "/wwwroot/dir/subdir">
      Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Other Restricted Files"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile /passwd/passwd.other.users
      AuthGroupFile /passwd/other.groups
      Require group other.People
    </Directory>
```

This doesn't seem to work at all.  Users from `some.People` still have access to `/wwwroot/dir/subdir`, and users from `other.People` don't authenticate at all.

---

I even tried this (which is not really what I want):

`httpd.conf`:

```
   <Directory "/wwwroot/dir">
      Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Files"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile /passwd/passwd.users
      AuthGroupFile /passwd/groups
      Require group some.People other.People
   </Directory>

   <Directory "/wwwroot/dir/subdir">
      Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Files"
      AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile /passwd/passwd.users
      AuthGroupFile /passwd/groups
      Require group other.People
    </Directory>
```

This is setup with a shared `AuthName` and shared set of group and user password files.  Even if this worked as I conceived it, this is not really what I want, since it would mean that `other.People` have access to the `/wwwroot/dir` parent directory.  However, even using this setup, I can't get `other.People` to successfully authenticate in `/wwwroot/dir/subdir`.

---

I found a slightly cryptic note in the apache docs that multiple `<Directory>` directives that apply to the same directory are evaluated in the order that they appear in the config file, so I also tried swapping the two section above around, but that didn't seem to make any difference.  There's another note, seemingly contradictory, that `<Directory>` directives are evaluated in order of shortest path to longest, which seems to me to indicate that `/wwwroot/dir` will always be processed before `/wwwroot/dir/subdir`.